# Difference between window.location.assign() and window.location.replace()

Tags: javascript, window.location

What is the difference between `window.location.assign()` and `window.location.replace()`, when both redirect to a new page?

Comment: Why is nobody explaining how this differs from `location.href = `??

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Using [`window.location.assign("url")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) will just cause a new document to load. Using [`window.location.replace("url")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) will replace the current document and replace the current History with that URL making it so you can't go back to the previous document loaded.

Reference: http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript-location-object.html

Answer (score 42):

The difference is how history is handled. "Replace" won't give you history, "assign" will.

Answer (score 34):

[According to MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Location_object)

> The difference from the `assign()` method is that after using `replace()` the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

Answer (score 16):

1. **location.assign():**

   To assign route path by passing path into it. Assign will give you a history even after path was assigned.

   **Usage Method:** Value should be passed into it.

   **Eg:** `location.assign("http://google.com")`

[image: location.assign()]

2. **location.replace():**

   It helps to replace path if you don't want to keep history. It won't give you a history once you replace its path.

   **Usage Method:** Value should be passed into it.

   **Eg:** `location.replace("http://google.com")`

[image: location.repalce()]