# JavaScript assign()

Tags: javascript

As far as I've tested, these two methods work, but I don't know which one is the best, or the differences between them, and that's what I'd like to know.

Here are the two methods:

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
window.location.assign = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two methods are equivalent. The first one is clearer to me. The syntax for `assign` would actually be:

`window.location.assign('http://www.google.com');`

Comment: They appear to have the same behaviour and there is one clear difference-- access to history.

Answer (score 1):

.assign() is actually a function.

The first is probably the most common.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is this:

window.location ='' /window.location.replace(''), replaces the current document in the browser and browser history

window.location.assign('') assigns a new document to the browser and history.

Effectively "replace" does not support returning to the previous view in history (potentially useful in some applications). "Assign" allows access to history.

[Difference between window.location.assign() and window.location.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505798/difference-between-window-location-assign-and-window-location-replace)