# How can I call to other web page with hidden parameter from email content?

Tags: java, javascript, html, email, gwt

I have a GWT project. I would like to call this gwt project from email content with parameters by clicking hyperlink. 
In this case, I would like to hide my parameters, so, I tried by adding javascript coding for passing hidden parameter. Unfortunately, javascript code cannot work in email content because of security issue.

Could anyone give me advise how can I call to my project with hidden parameters from email content ?

Comment: hope bc means because

Comment: Why do you want to hide the parameters?

Comment: When calling a GWT project with parameter, this parameters are show on url bar in all page. So, I would like to hide my parameter from url bar as a post request. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good thing, that email clients don't allow this (think about the security risks). Links generally aren't meant to perform a POST request.

So if you don't want to have the GET parameters in your browser's URL, the way to solve this is [sending a redirect](http://www.javatpoint.com/sendRedirect%28%29-method) when you receive the request. (An alternative would be to change the URL immediately on the client side using  [`Window.Location.replace()` or `Window.Location.assign()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505798/difference-between-window-location-assign-and-window-location-replace) .)

Answer (score 0):

Use a jsp file for your module:

Call you jsp with parameters like myModule.jsp?user='123'&mail='456'

in the jsp code write the parameters to your HTML output

```
<input id='userName' type='hidden' value='<%=user%>'>
```

Get the values in the result html from your gwt code: when the GWT is executed, the page html is already rendered.

*If you use the Place-Activity mechanism, do a placeController.goTo() using a place constructed with these parameters*