# I want a conditional redirection Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a small javascript code which will check for a div class and if it's not there then it will redirect the page to a site which is specified in javascript code.

I have this code, but I want it in `document.getElementById` form because I'm learning and I tried making the code. The below code is jQuery which I found here on this site.

```
function check() {
  if ($('#demodivclass').length === 0) {
    redirect(somesite.com);
  }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you mean `window.location.href = ''`?

Comment: you can use window.location.href = 'somesite.com'

Comment: What you've got is not checking for a class, it's checking for an id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Conditional redirect and not just redirect.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a class exists on an element you can use `classList.contains()`. Then you can redirect with `location.assign()`, like this:

```
function check() {
  if (!document.getElementById('demodivclass').classList.contains('foo')) {
    window.location.assign('http://somesite.com');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a code which will not redirect when specified div class is present but redirect in absence.

Comment: In which case you just need to invert the logic by adding `!` at the start of the condition. I edited the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in order to check either a div has a specific classname and redirect after condition meets by using JQuery.

**JQuery**

```
if($( "#yourdivId" ).hasClass( "classname" ))
{
  window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");  
}
```

**Javascript**

```
if(document.getElementById('yourdivId').className == 'classname') 
{
   window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");  
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I believe OP doesn't want to use jQuery

Comment: I need the same code but in getelementbyid form as stated in my question. Is this possible?

Comment: Use this condition: if(document.getElementById('yourdivId').className == 'classname')

Answer (score 0):

What the jQuery part of your code is doing is looking for elements with the id `demodivclass` using the [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Using the [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) function as shown below will achieve the same thing.

If you want to check if a div that has a specific class exists (based on your question) the [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function can be used instead.

To redirect the page use either `location.replace` or `location.assign`. Differences are highlighted at [Difference between window.location.assign() and window.location.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505798/difference-between-window-location-assign-and-window-location-replace)

**Redirect if ID does not exist:**

```
function check() {
  if (!document.getElementById('demodivclass')) {

    window.location.replace("somesite.com");
    // or
    window.location.assign("somesite.com");
  }
}
```

**Redirect if class does not exist:**

```
function check() {
  if (!document.querySelector(".demodivclass")) {

    window.location.replace("somesite.com");
    // or
    window.location.assign("somesite.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the code is checking for a div class and if present then redirecting to another site.

But, I want just opposite of this case. 
The code should first check for a div id.
Then if it's there no redirection should happen.

If divid is not there then only redirection should happen.

Comment: @SumantSingh that is what the first code block in my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to select your DOM element, you need to use `getElementById` with your ID that you defined previously. Then, to check if there is a class settled, you need to use `classList.contains()` method. Finally, to make a URL redirection, use `window.location.href = 'Your link'`.

```
function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('element').classList.contains('class')) {
        window.location.href = 'newPage.html';
    }
}
```

Good luck and keep learning.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote while an identical answer got an upvote!  Maybe add a bit more info as this is otherwise essentially just a 'code-only' answer.

Comment: Yes, do you not have an 'edit' button at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: Oh yeah ! I see it.

Comment: As I'm still learning I might make mistake understanding your code. But, I think it's not fulfilling my need.

What I need is a code that will look for a div class by getelementbyid and then starts the condition.
If divclass is there then code should not redirect but if it's not there then there should be a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if($( "#div" ).hasClass( "divClass" )) /// check Is Exists or not
      location.assign("https://stackoverflow.com");
 else
      alert('class not exist!')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div" class="divClass"></div>
```

try this one. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

```
function check() {
  if ($('#demodivclass').length < 1) {
    window.location.href = 'somesite.com';
  }
```

Please try the following code, it is similar to your code. I just changed a little code of checking statement.

Comment: I'm not looking for jquery code. I think it's jquery in your answer. Is it possible to make it in getelementbyid format?

Comment: `if (!document.getElementById("somediv")) ` You can try this in your if statement. It check if somediv doesn't exist then you can do something.